# One authorization key with passcode and biometrics to encrypt local data on Android

Tags: android, cryptography, android-security

I want to use one secure key to encrypt and decrypt data on device without saving it in SharedPreferences or DataStore. I want to generate that key using in app authorization (passcode and biometrics).

I know generating secure key with biometrics is possible using AndroidKeyStore. I know I can generate another key by using passcode. Is there any cryptographic way to use one of those keys to encrypt/decrypt local data?

I have tried generating keys with biometrics and passcode. But I could not find a way to encrypt and decrypt data with either of those keys. For example: user logs in and sets passcode and fingerprint. App should encrypt data so it could be decrypted using one of those authentication methods.

I am wondering how do other secure Android apps solve this problem. Can someone provide me an example where could I look into that?

Comment: By "Is there any cryptographic way to use one of those keys to encrypt/decrypt local data?" you mean that you want both these ways(key generated with a password and key generated with fingerprint) to be able to decrypt the same app data?

Comment: Yes. I have come up with a solution to use AndroidKeyStore key with device credentials (biometrics or passcode). But I haven't found a solution to use biometrics and in app passcode.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most robust ways is to generate a symmetric key(I would call it **data encryption key**), encrypt the app's data with it and then save this key encrypted by another key(I would call it **authorized encryption key**).

When the application wants to decrypt its data it needs first to use the **authorized encryption key** to decrypt the **data encryption key** and then use it to decrypt the data itself.

It might be done for biometrics and password following way:

- first of all, as you will have two auth methods available the easiest approach would be to have two copies of **data encryption key** encrypted with two different **authorized encryption keys** (different for biometrics and different for passwords).

**Biometrics**

- in that case the **data encryption key** is encrypted by the key authorised by the user's biometrics, you can check how to do it in this  [article](https://medium.com/csg-govtech/how-you-should-secure-your-androids-app-biometric-authentication-10d9231215e4)(especially "How to implement local authentication securely?" section)
- so the user needs to confirm **authorized encryption key** usage by his biometrics in order to be able to use it to decrypt the **data encryption key**

**Password**

- you can just use one of the key derivation functions to create an **authorized encryption key** based on the user's password, here is the [example](https://medium.com/@lucideus/secure-derivation-of-keys-in-android-pbkdf2-lucideus-371452cc29f7)
- so every time user will provide his password you are generating the **authorized encryption key** from it and use it to decrypt the **data encryption key**.